# linking a sub xml file to exist xml result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

the home page

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="process()">
    <div id="theD">

    </div>

<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="read.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

the js

```
function process()
{
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }


xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

    names=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("CategoryName");
    var stuff ;

    for (var i=0;i<names.length;i++)
      {
        stuff += names.item(i).firstChild.data + "<br/>";

      }
    theD = document.getElementById("theD");
         theD.innerHTML = stuff;

    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","categories.xml",true);

xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

the main xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CategoriesRoot>
    <Categories>
        <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Beverages</CategoryName>
        <Description>Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beer, and ale</Description>
    </Categories>
    <Categories>
        <CategoryID>2</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Condiments</CategoryName>
        <Description>Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings</Description>
    </Categories>
    <Categories>
        <CategoryID>3</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Confections</CategoryName>
        <Description>Desserts, candies, sweetbreads</Description>
    </Categories>
    <Categories>
        <CategoryID>4</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Dairy Products</CategoryName>
        <Description>Cheeses</Description>
    </Categories>
    <Categories>
        <CategoryID>5</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Grains/Cereals</CategoryName>
        <Description>Breads, crackers, pasta, and cereal</Description>
    </Categories>
    <Categories>
        <CategoryID>6</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Meat/Poultry</CategoryName>
        <Description>Prepared meats</Description>
    </Categories>
    <Categories>
        <CategoryID>7</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Produce</CategoryName>
        <Description>Dried fruit and bean curd</Description>
    </Categories>
    <Categories>
        <CategoryID>8</CategoryID>
        <CategoryName>Seafood</CategoryName>
        <Description>Seaweed and fish</Description>
    </Categories>
</CategoriesRoot>
```

now I can display all the categoryname. but next i need to add some productname under each categoryname.

the products xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProductsRoot>
    <Products>
        <ProductID>1</ProductID>
        <ProductName>Chai</ProductName>
        <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
        <QuantityPerUnit>10 boxes x 20 bags</QuantityPerUnit>
        <UnitPrice>18</UnitPrice>
    </Products>
    <Products>
        <ProductID>2</ProductID>
        <ProductName>Chang</ProductName>
        <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
        <QuantityPerUnit>24 - 12 oz bottles</QuantityPerUnit>
        <UnitPrice>19</UnitPrice>
    </Products>
    <Products>
        <ProductID>3</ProductID>
        <ProductName>Aniseed Syrup</ProductName>
        <CategoryID>2</CategoryID>
        <QuantityPerUnit>12 - 550 ml bottles</QuantityPerUnit>
        <UnitPrice>10</UnitPrice>
    </Products>
    <Products>
        <ProductID>4</ProductID>
        <ProductName>Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning</ProductName>
        <CategoryID>2</CategoryID>
        <QuantityPerUnit>48 - 6 oz jars</QuantityPerUnit>
        <UnitPrice>22</UnitPrice>
    </Products>
    <Products>
        <ProductID>5</ProductID>
        <ProductName>Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix</ProductName>
        <CategoryID>2</CategoryID>
        <QuantityPerUnit>36 boxes</QuantityPerUnit>
        <UnitPrice>21.35</UnitPrice>
    </Products>
    <Products>
        <ProductID>6</ProductID>
        <ProductName>Chef Anton's Gumbo</ProductName>
        <CategoryID>2</CategoryID>
        <QuantityPerUnit>36 boxes</QuantityPerUnit>
        <UnitPrice>21.35</UnitPrice>
    </Products>
    <Products>
        <ProductID>7</ProductID>
        <ProductName>hamburger bun</ProductName>
        <CategoryID>5</CategoryID>
        <QuantityPerUnit>36 boxes</QuantityPerUnit>
        <UnitPrice>25.5</UnitPrice>
    </Products> 
    <Products>
        <ProductID>8</ProductID>
        <ProductName>turkish bread</ProductName>
        <CategoryID>5</CategoryID>
        <QuantityPerUnit>36 boxes</QuantityPerUnit>
        <UnitPrice>21.5</UnitPrice>
    </Products>
  <Products>
        <ProductID>9</ProductID>
        <ProductName>bread roll</ProductName>
        <CategoryID>5</CategoryID>
        <QuantityPerUnit>50 boxes</QuantityPerUnit>
        <UnitPrice>25.5</UnitPrice>
    </Products> 
<Products>
        <ProductID>10</ProductID>
        <ProductName>beef burger</ProductName>
        <CategoryID>6</CategoryID>
        <QuantityPerUnit>12 boxes</QuantityPerUnit>
        <UnitPrice>50.5</UnitPrice>
    </Products> 
<Products>
        <ProductID>11</ProductID>
        <ProductName>chicken burger</ProductName>
        <CategoryID>6</CategoryID>
        <QuantityPerUnit>12 boxes</QuantityPerUnit>
        <UnitPrice>54.5</UnitPrice>
    </Products>    
<Products>
        <ProductID>12</ProductID>
        <ProductName>tiger prawns</ProductName>
        <CategoryID>8</CategoryID>
        <QuantityPerUnit>12 boxes</QuantityPerUnit>
        <UnitPrice>70.5</UnitPrice>
    </Products> 
<Products>
        <ProductID>13</ProductID>
        <ProductName>cooked prawns</ProductName>
        <CategoryID>8</CategoryID>
        <QuantityPerUnit>12 boxes</QuantityPerUnit>
        <UnitPrice>65.9</UnitPrice>
    </Products>     
 </ProductsRoot>
```

under this products.xml, we can see each product has the categryID which should link to the category.xml file. 
the result should like

```
Beverages
Chai
Chang

Condiments
Aniseed Syrup
Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning
```

I can not do it... please help!thank you so much!